# getting errore parsing a json file

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to extract data from a json file received from a web.i used newtonsoft library
i'm using this code :

```
Dim JSONtxt As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\prova.json")
Dim account As Person = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person)(JSONtxt)
```

the class is :

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property validationType As String
    Public Property lastName As String
    Public Property firstName As String
End Class
```

unfortunately account does not get any value....
how can be ??
thanks for you help

this is my json :

```
{"listReservationReport":[{"validationType":"PRESENTE","bookingId":"xxxxx","travelId":null,"travelSolutionId":null,"couponId":"xxxxxx","transportMeanName":"aereo","transportClassification":"az","transportMeanDate":"16-01-2020","couponServiceType":"Posto a sedere","materializationType":"NON MATERIALIZZATO","fila":"6","seat":"2A","pnrCode":"xxxxxx","departureLocationName":"NAPOLI capodichino","arrivalLocationName":"ROMA fiumicino","cpCode":"xxxxxxx","offerName":"Super Economy","serviceLevel":"2° Premium","amount":"109,90","adults":1,"teens":0,"alreadyPaied":"--","alreadyCached":"--","ci204":"PRESENTE","firstName":"xxxxxxxx","lastName":"xxxxxx","channelName":"Internet B2C","gender":"Non disponibile","saleSystem":"galileo","travellerInfo":null,"validation":null},{"validationType":"PRESENTE","bookingId":"xxxxx","travelId":null,"travelSolutionId":null,"couponId":"xxxxxx","transportMeanName":"aereo","transportClassification":"az","transportMeanDate":"16-01-2020","couponServiceType":"Posto a sedere","materializationType":"NON MATERIALIZZATO","fila":"6","seat":"2A","pnrCode":"xxxxxx","departureLocationName":"NAPOLI capodichino","arrivalLocationName":"ROMA fiumicino","cpCode":"xxxxxxx","offerName":"Super Economy","serviceLevel":"2° Premium","amount":"109,90","adults":1,"teens":0,"alreadyPaied":"--","alreadyCached":"--","ci204":"PRESENTE","firstName":"xxxxxxxx","lastName":"xxxxxx","channelName":"Internet B2C","gender":"Non disponibile","saleSystem":"galileo","travellerInfo":null,"validation":null},{"validationType":"PRESENTE","bookingId":"xxxxx","travelId":null,"travelSolutionId":null,"couponId":"xxxxxx","transportMeanName":"aereo","transportClassification":"az","transportMeanDate":"16-01-2020","couponServiceType":"Posto a sedere","materializationType":"NON MATERIALIZZATO","fila":"6","seat":"2A","pnrCode":"xxxxxx","departureLocationName":"NAPOLI capodichino","arrivalLocationName":"ROMA fiumicino","cpCode":"xxxxxxx","offerName":"Super Economy","serviceLevel":"2° Premium","amount":"109,90","adults":1,"teens":0,"alreadyPaied":"--","alreadyCached":"--","ci204":"PRESENTE","firstName":"xxxxxxxx","lastName":"xxxxxx","channelName":"Internet B2C","gender":"Non disponibile","saleSystem":"galileo","travellerInfo":null,"validation":null}],"validatorList":[{"firstName":"xxxxx","lastName":"xxxx","roleId":"USR","enterpriseRoleType":"CST"},{"firstName":"xxxx ","lastName":"xxxx ","roleId":"xxx","enterpriseRoleType":"CT"},{"firstName":"x","lastName":"xxxx ","roleId":"USR","enterpriseRoleType":"CPV"},{"firstName":"xxx","lastName":"xxx","roleId":"USR","enterpriseRoleType":"CT"}],"materializedStatus":[{"onboard":30,"absent":0,"none":1,"defect":0,"undo":0}],"notMaterializedStatus":[{"onboard":522,"absent":0,"none":110,"defect":0,"undo":0}]}
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. `"validation":null},]`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: account has "nothing" value

Comment: Try using to see if your format is correct: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: It looks like you have commas as if you're using an JArray, but you only have one object in there.

Comment: json is correct;it is a jarray,it's a reservation list,but i don't understand why account doesn't get any value

Comment: It is bad JSON. I just tested with properly formatted JSON and it works fine.  You need to re-format it....run it through that converter until you get the green light.

Comment: i tested now and it comes up green;at the beginning  (20 min ago) it was wrong as u told me,now it works :)

Comment: I posted a different solution.  I think the issue is because the JSON contains an array... so which index does it know to deserialize? You need to loop through each one and then deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, give this a try....

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Partial Class _testPW22
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Class Person
        Public Property validationType As String
        Public Property lastName As String
        Public Property firstName As String
    End Class

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim JSONtxt As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\prova.json")
        Dim ob As JObject = JObject.Parse(JSONtxt)

        Dim persons As New Collection(Of Person)()

        For Each item As JObject In ob.SelectToken("listReservationReport")
            Dim test As Person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person)(item.ToString())
            persons.Add(test)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```